# Why does $-1<\frac{7}{x+4}$ imply $x<-11$? I keep getting $x>-11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve for the $|\frac{7}{x+4}|<1$. Which becomes $-1<\frac{7}{x+4}<1$.

Evaluating the positive side is fine, $3<x,$ but for the negative side:

$-1<\frac{7}{x+4}$ should evaluate to $-11 > x$. But I keep getting $-11 < x.$

My working:

$$-1<\frac{7}{x+4}\\
-1(x+4)<7\\-x < 11\\
x>-11.$$

This results in the answer $x>-11,  x>3,$ which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I did that at step d, did I do it wrong..?

Comment: $(x+4)$ is a variable expression. I don't think you can multiply both sides of the inequality by it, since we do not know whether $(x+4)$ is a positive or a negative term.

Comment: @sonicsid, i did not know this. Is there a source or good video about that? 
Also how else do we solve it if we can't multiply both sides by (x+4)..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for clarity.

---

Expanding on the comment of sonicsid, when you are faced with the necessity of clearing the denominator of $(x + 4)$, since $x + 4 = 0$ is disallowed, you must break the analysis into two cases:

Case 1: $(x + 4) > 0.$ 
$-1 < \frac{7}{x+4} < 1.$ 
$ (-1) (x+4) < 7 < (x+4).$ 
$(x + 4) > -7$ and $(x + 4) > 7.$

This means that all three of the following constraints must be satisfied for Case 1:

- $x > -4.$
- $x > -11.$
- $x > 3.$

Therefore, the Case 1 solutions resolve to 
$x > 3.$

---

Case 2: $(x + 4) < 0.$ 
$-1 < \frac{7}{x+4} < 1.$ 
$(-1) (x + 4) > 7$ and $7 > (x + 4).$

This means that all three of the following constraints must be satisfied for Case 2:

- $x < -4.$
- $x < -11.$
- $x < 3.$

Therefore, the Case 2 solutions resolve to 
$x < -11.$

---

Putting Case 1 and Case 2 together:

Either $x > 3$ or $x < -11.$

Comment: What is "something else" in constraints 2 and 4 in your answer? So what you're saying is that x is either x>-4 or x<-4...? I don't get why we need to add a counter statement "(x+4) < 0" since the original statement is $\frac{7}{(x+4)}>0$ to start with.

Comment: @nvs0000 Answer edited for clarity.

Comment: Thanks it seems like switching reciprocal & signs is the way to do it fast. Other answers were great too and really explained it well. But yours explained it and gave am effective way to work it through.

Answer (score 3):

You can't multiply $(x+4) $ both sides as you don't know it is positive or negative.

Correct way: $\dfrac{7}{x+4}>-1$

$ \dfrac{7}{x+4}+1>0 \implies \dfrac{x+11}{x+4}>0$

So

- either $x+11$ and $x+4$ both are $>$ than $0$ for which we get $x>-4$
- or both less than $0$ for which we get $x<-11$

Comment: Aren't we multiplying both side when we do this "$\dfrac{x+11}{x+4}>0$" in order to get x too...?

Comment: @nvs0000 sorry for that mistake please check now

Comment: Per your point 
"$+11$ and $+4$ both are > than 0 for which we get >−4", would we then get $x > -11$ as well..? (Which is the wrong answer..)

Comment: *IF* $x +4 > 0$ then you have i) $x >-4$ and ii) $x >3$ and iii) $x > -11$.  Combining we get $-11 < -4 < 3 < x$.  So $x > 3$..... *IF* $x + 4 < 0$ we get i) $x < -4$ and ii) $x < 3$ and iii) $x <-11$.  Combining them we get $x<-11 < -4 < 3$.  So $x <-11$.....One or the other is true... so we have a) $x > 3$  *OR*  $x < -11$.

Comment: Thanks fleablood maybe @nvs0000 you will get your answer by fleablood comment

Comment: Thanks @fleablood , so we need to basically map out all possibilities of x and draw it on a number line, then identify which inequality is a catch all..?

Comment: There are quicker ways that come with practide.  The thing is if you *ever* multiply both sides of an inequality by an expression with a variable *always* get in the habit of asking yourself if it is positive.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{7}{x+4}>-1 \implies \frac{x+11}{x+4} >0$$
This means

(1): $(x+11)>0 \& x+4>0 \implies x>-4 \& x >-11 \implies x>-4$

(2): $(x+11) <0 \& x+4 <0 \implies x<-11 \& x <-4 \implies x<-11$

So the total answer is union of the two: $x\in (-\infty, -11) \cup (-4, \infty)$ or
$x<-11$ or $x >-4$.

Comment: Aren't we multiplying both side when we do this "$\dfrac{x+11}{x+4}>0$" in order to get x too...? Which was what everyone in the thread is saying.. not to do.

Comment: also @zAhmed why would we want to flip the equality sign and solve for (2)?.. What the logical reason for flipping that equality sign?

Comment: Note that $A>B \implies A-B>0$ always.$ AB>0 or A/B>0 \implies A>0 \& B>0$; or $A<0 \& B<0$.

Comment: Ok I get the logic now thank you! I have to compare it against each and every possibility [like so](https://ibb.co/FHcPTtT)? it's such a long method though, is there a quicker one?

Comment: @nvs0000 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: thanks @JitendraSingh, I have given the points, but am trying to find a shorter way. Currently finding every single bound to get one side of the inequaility requires us to find every single answer of A/B>0. Specifically trying to understand how Rezha did it.

Comment: Your solution seems to be defective: observer tha $x=0$ is no solution ...

Comment: Sir, $x=0$ is very much a solution as $7/4>-1.$

Answer (score 1):

I also used to find it difficult so what I did was take $y=x+4$ then the equation transforms to $7/|y|<1$. Now break it into cases.

Case:$1$(y<0)
then $7/-y<1 \implies 7<-y \implies -7>y \implies y \in (-\infty,-7)$

Case:$1$(y>0)
then $7/y<1 \implies 7<y \implies 7<y \implies y \in (7,\infty)$

Now put $y=x+4$ to get the result

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative**

Make sure you only multiply with positive number because otherwise the inequality sign will reverse

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|&<1\cdot\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|\\
\\
&<1\cdot 1\\
\\
\\
7^{2}&<(x+4)^{2}
\end{align}
$$

From here we get the solutions:

$$
x<-11\text{ or }x>3
$$

Notice that I only multiply with $\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|$ and $(x+4)^{2}$ which I know are positive numbers.

Comment: Interesting. I like how short this is, but how do we get from $\frac{7}{x+4} \cdot| \frac{7}{x+4} |<1 \cdot | \frac{7}{x+4}\implies<1 \cdot 1$?

Comment: @nvs0000 $\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|^{2}=\frac{7^{2}}{(x+4)^{2}}$ then multiply by $(x+4)^{2}$

Comment: More specifically, how do we get from $-1<\frac{7}{x+4} \implies \frac{7}{x+4} \cdot| \frac{7}{x+4} |<1 \cdot | \frac{7}{x+4}$

Comment: I tired squaring both sides to get rid of the negative sign [here](https://ibb.co/5RYWjvd), but it seems like there's no getting away from multiplying both sides from (x+c).

Comment: If you want to proceed from $-1<\frac{7}{x+4}$, simply multiply by $(x+4)^{2}$

Comment: @poetasis yeah? Even though $-12$ clearly satisfy the inequality?

Comment: @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja    You are right and I am humbled.

Answer (score 1):

If $k>0$, then $a<b\iff ak<bk$. However, if $k<0$, then $a<b\iff ak\color{red}{>}bk$.

So when multiplying an inequality by a constant, we should be certain whether that constant is positive or negative. In the case of $-1<\frac{7}{x+4}$, multiplying by $x+4$ is not a good idea because we don't know if $x+4<0$ or $x+4>0$. A better idea is to multiply by $(x+4)^2$, which is positive.* Then,
\begin{align}
-1<\frac{7}{x+4}&\iff-(x+4)^2<7(x+4) \\[5pt]
&\iff -x^2-8x-16<7x+28 \\[5pt]
&\iff 0<x^2+15x+44 \\[5pt]
&\iff0<(x+4)(x+11) \\[5pt]
&\iff x<-11\text{ or }x>-4 \, .
\end{align}

---

*Technically, $(x+4)^2$ could also be zero, if $x=-4$. However, this is a non-issue, as if $x=-4$, then $7/(x+4)$ is undefined, so it is not a solution to $-1<7/(x+4)$; and $x=-4$ is not a solution to $-(x+4)^2<7(x+4)$ either.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed you went wrong multiplying for a quantity which can also be negative.

Using that for $A,B>0$ then
$$|A|<B \iff \left|\frac1{A}\right|>\frac1B $$

a very effective way to proceed in this case is the following

$$\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|<1 \iff \left|\frac{x+4}{7}\right|>1 \iff |x+4|>7$$

$$\iff x+4<-7 \quad \lor \quad x+4 >7 $$

$$\iff x<-11 \quad \lor \quad x>3 $$

We can also proceed by your way but we need to consider two cases, that is

- For $x+4>0 \iff x>-4$

$$\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|<1\iff \frac{7}{x+4}<1\iff x+4>7 \iff x>3$$

- For $x+4<0 \iff x<-4$

$$\left|\frac{7}{x+4}\right|<1\iff \frac{7}{-(x+4)}<1\iff -(x+4)>7\iff x+4<-7 \iff x<-11$$

Comment: @poetasis Sorry I don’t see the mistake.

Comment: Try it without the absolute value: $\quad -1<\dfrac{1}{x+4}<1\quad$ and you will find $x>3,\quad X>-11$

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the noise, this is how I would personally attack this problem.  This is a matter of personal style and may not work for you.

$|\frac 7{x+4}| < 1$.

Either $\frac 7{x+4}$ is non-negative (positive or zero) or it is negative.

It is positive if $x+4$ is positive.  It is negative if $x+4$ is negative.  (And it is never $0$ as $\frac ab \ne 0; a=0$ and we can't have $x+4 = 0$ as we can't have $0$ in a denominator).

Case 1:

If $\frac 7{x+4}$ is positive then $x+4$ is positive and then 1) $x > -4$ and 2) $|\frac 7{x+4}| =\frac 7{x+4}$ and $x + 4 > 0$.

So.... $\frac 7{x+4} > 1\implies 7 < x+4 \implies 3<x $ and combining that with $x > -4$ we get.... $x > 3$.

Case 2:

If $\frac 7{x+4}$ is negative then $x+4$ is negative and 1) $x < -4$ and 2) $|\frac 7{x+4}| =\frac 7{-(x+4)}$ and $-(x + 4) > 0$.

So.... $\frac 7{-(x+4)} < 1\implies 7 < -(x+4) = -x -4\implies x< -11$ and combining that with $x< -4$ we get.... $x<-11$.

....

So Case 1: $x > 3$ and Case 2: $x < -11$.

So $x < -11$ or $x > 3$ and the solution set is:

$(-\infty, -11) \cup (3, \infty) =$

$\{$ everything that *isn't* between $-11$ and $3\}=$

$\mathbb R \setminus [-11,3]$.